# Create dynamic strings inside a for loop to generate multiple strings

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I'm working on a Python(3.6) project in which I need to create some strings on the base of some input parameters.

Here's my code:

```
def generate_multi_svc_config(data):
    no_of_svc = int(data['configuration']['no_of_svc'])
    deployments = ''''''
    services = ''''''
    for var in list(range(1, no_of_svc + 1)):
        services = services + '''\n
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {}
  labels:
    app: {}
spec:
  ports:
  - port: {}
    name: {}
  selector:
    app: {}
---
'''.format(data['configuration']['svc' + str(var)]['name'],
           data['configuration']['svc' + str(var)]['name'],
           data['configuration']['svc' + str(var)]['versions']['v1']['port']['port'],
           data['configuration']['svc' + str(var)]['versions']['v1']['port']['name'],
           data['configuration']['svc' + str(var)]['name'])
        print(services)
        deployments = deployments + '''\n
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {}
  labels:
    #Project ID
    app: {}
spec:
  #Run two instances of our application
  replicas: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {}
    spec:
      #Container details
      containers:
        - name: {}
          image: {}
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          #Ports to expose
          ports:
          - containerPort: {}
            name: {}
---
'''.format(data['configuration']['svc' + str(var)]['name'] + '-' + 'v1',
           data['configuration']['svc' + str(var)]['name'],
           data['configuration']['svc' + str(var)]['replicas'],
           data['configuration']['svc' + str(var)]['name'],
           data['configuration']['svc' + str(var)]['name'],
           data['configuration']['svc' + str(var)]['versions']['v1']['image'],
           data['configuration']['svc' + str(var)]['versions']['v1']['port']['port'],
           data['configuration']['svc' + str(var)]['versions']['v1']['port']['name'])
    print(deployments)
```

So, when I pass `no_of_svc = 2` it should create 2 service strings and 2 deployments string.

But it created the first entry in services for twice and all others for once.
I don't know why it's creating the first service string twice?

Here's the example output:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ratings
  labels:
    app: ratings
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    name: ratings-port
  selector:
    app: ratings
---



apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ratings
  labels:
    app: ratings
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    name: ratings-port
  selector:
    app: ratings
---


apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: reviews
  labels:
    app: reviews
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8081
    name: reviews-port
  selector:
    app: reviews
---



apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ratings-v1
  labels:
    #Project ID
    app: ratings
spec:
  #Run two instances of our application
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ratings
    spec:
      #Container details
      containers:
        - name: ratings
          image: gcr.io/ml001-208807/node-app:0.0.1
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          #Ports to expose
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
            name: ratings-port
---


apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: reviews-v1
  labels:
    #Project ID
    app: reviews
spec:
  #Run two instances of our application
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: reviews
    spec:
      #Container details
      containers:
        - name: reviews
          image: gcr.io/ml001-208807/node-app1:0.0.1
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          #Ports to expose
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8081
            name: reviews-port
---
```

Comment: Those large multiline strings really make your code hard to read. Move them to some module-level constants. Might also help readability to define `tmp = data['configuration']['svc' + str(var)]`.

Comment: .... then you might notice that the `print(deployments)` line is _outside_ of the loop, while `print(services)` is inside. Could this be the problem?

Comment: both are inside the loop!

Comment: Nope, they are not. Check the indentation. Also, this explains why the services are printed repeatedly, but the deployments are not

Comment: Also, note that I rolled back your question; as I said, chaning the code in your question invalidates all the answers. If you want to provide updated, do so _below_ your original code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you append to `services` and `deployments` in each iteration of the loop, but while you print `deployments` only at the end, you print `services` *in each iteration* of the loop, hence printing the entry that was added in the first iteration twice.

Due to the large multiline-strings this is hard to see in your original code. I suggest extracting those strings to some constants on module-level to make the loop body much easier to read. Also, you can define some temporary variable to shorten the repeated dict lookup:

```
template1 = '''\n
apiVersion: v1
... more lines ...
    app: {}
---
'''
template2 = '''\n
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
... more lines ...
            name: {}
---
'''
def generate_multi_svc_config(data):
    no_of_svc = int(data['configuration']['no_of_svc'])
    deployments = ''
    services = ''
    for var in list(range(1, no_of_svc + 1)):
        d = data['configuration']['svc' + str(var)]
        services += template1.format(d['name'],
           d['name'],
           d['versions']['v1']['port']['port'],
           d['versions']['v1']['port']['name'],
           d['name'])
        deployments += template2.format(d['name'] + '-' + 'v1',
           d['name'],
           d['replicas'],
           d['name'],
           d['name'],
           d['versions']['v1']['image'],
           d['versions']['v1']['port']['port'],
           d['versions']['v1']['port']['name'])
    print(services) # <- move this line here, outside the loop
    print(deployments)
```

Also, if you want to insert certain values at multiple places in your template string, you can use placeholders like `{0}` or `{1}`, so you don't have to pass `d["name"]` three times.

```
>>> template = "first {0} second {1} first again {0}"
>>> template.format("foo", "bar")
'first foo second bar first again foo'
```

Answer (score 2):

Because on each iteration you're printing an actual content of `services` variable, that, in turn, contents currently formed service alongside all previously added.

Simply put, your loop works like this:

```
no_of_svc = 2
services = ''
for var in range(1, no_of_svc + 1):
    services += "{} service\n".format(var)
    print(services)
```

So, on the second iteration, `services` contains first and second service. As a result, the first service has been printed on both iterations.

If you need to save all values to the `services` variable as a string, simply print only current value before appending:

```
no_of_svc = 2
services = ''
for var in range(1, no_of_svc + 1):
    service = "service {}\n".format(var)
    print(service)
    services += service
```

Comment: Hi @OlegRybalchenko, I have changed my code according to your solution but still the first `service`  created twice.

Comment: @AbdulRehman Nope, you did not. You just changed `services = services + ...` to `services += ...`, which is exactly the same thing. Also, please do NOT change the code in your question. If you want to provide an update, do so BELOW your original code, otherwise you invalidate all the existing answers and comments.

Comment: So, what I need to change? please!

Comment: Hi @tobias_k, now I have updated my code, does it indented correctly?

Comment: @AbdulRehman No, you moved _both_ print statements _inside_ the loop instead of outside.